# How to overwrite a csv file ('w' doesn't work well)

Tags: python, csv

I want to overwrite the data in a CSV file when my code runs a second time. I've been using the `a+` mode when opening the CSV file and `w` for writing. However, the new data is getting appended to the existing file instead of overwriting it. How do I overwrite the file?

Here's my code:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\news.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    if file.tell()==0:
        writer.writerow(['title', 'news', 'img-url'])
    if writer.writerow != 0:
        writer.writerow([title,news,img])
return writer
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean "w" isn't working good? Can you elaborate on what kind of problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Please give some example csv files that show your problems. And please learn how to use commas in long sentences :)

Comment: @altskop 
means that if i use w for over writing then it wil shows the data like this
"m y  n  a  m e  i  s t h i s"

Comment: @tomAtix i will use next time

Answer (score 0):

Call [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=truncate#os.truncate) to clear the file before writing to it.

Comment: bro can you tell me with an example ?